# Fields overflow in IE on windows only

Tags: css, windows, browser

I cannot figure out why these few fields on my checkout are overflowing when view on a windows machine. It happens in both IE and FF.

Here is the page in question:
https://www.theatticlight.com/checkout/

As you can see in the box titles You Billing Information, the grey alt line boxes hang out over the edge. This happens only in this box, but not to the others with the same css classes on the rest of the page.

One of the last details to hammer out on this one, I would be very appreciative to anyone who give me an idea of another place to look.

Thank you!

Comment: need to register to view?  Possible for you to put an isolated version of the page somewhere that can be viewed?

Comment: You have some layout issues with stray tags.  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theatticlight.com%2Faccount%2Flogin%2F%3Fredirect_to%3D%2Fdeals%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: see my answer and try the css and let me know if any issues..

Comment: Mike - I have set the page up here: http://www.theatticlight.com/checkout.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the css rules:

Style.css line 288

```
table td, table th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    border-right: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You have given padding: 10px 15px; which is increasing the width of the table and you fill the background of the td thats why table is overlapping the form container.

I reduced the td padding to 10px;

Screen Shot: http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/2769/cellspacingissue.jpg

Comment: Doesnt it seem strange that this is only happening to this box, where all the other boxes on the page use the same css class, but dont have the problem. This does work but its not the real solution...